# Table with pagination, sorting and search in a PL/SQL Dynamic Content

Tags: bootstrap-4, oracle-apex

i have a table that basically looks like this:

```
begin
htp.p('
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th>ID</th> 
            <th>First Name</th> 
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>'); 

    for i in(select * from exampleTable)
    loop

        htp.p('
        <tr>
            <td>'||i.id||'</td>
            <td>'||i.first_Name||'</td>
            <td>'||i.last_name||'</td>
            <td>'||i.email||'</td>
            <td>'||i.Coubtry||'</td>
        </tr>');
    end loop;
    htp.p('
    <tbody>
</table>');
end;
```

is it possible to use the Apex's built in functions to do this (and how) or do I have to build my own functions.
also is Bootstrap integrated with Apex (meaning I can use it without importing it) because I have found some solutions with Bootstrap that i can use after some tweaks of course.
also is it possible to merge the rows where the country is the same into 1 row while leaving the other columns separated

Comment: It seems like what you want is just a APEX report region with your query.  But I'm not sure where this code is supposed to be (i.e. is there a stored procedure that is generating a bunch of HTML for some reason).

Comment: i need to display data in rows and column that has to be grouped (or merged) which can't be done by an interactive report

Comment: OK.  So then I'm confused.  I'm not seeing any grouping or merging of data in the code you posted.  And you can do quite a lot of grouping and merging in an interactive report.  Perhaps you could expand your question a bit to show more of what you're doing in code and more of what you've tried to do in an equivalent interactive report and what functionality the interactive report wasn't able to duplicate.

Comment: all right, will do